# Xcode ignores icon and splash screen in PhoneGap config.xml file

Tags: cordova, xcode4.2

I have a config file in the www directory in a PhoneGap Xcode project, and everything works great (features are being picked up, for example), but Xcode ignores the other tags - such as icon and splash screen. In a the same app, but built for Android, it does pick up and use these tags. So, does the config.xml file in Xcode really only specify phonegap features and the other tags just not work, or am I missing something? I get that if I use build.phonegap.com then it does use these values, but I guess thats part of their automatic build system.

A follow up question, if you have to manually specify the icons/splash screen in Xcode is there a way to specify a build rule so that it grabs them from the config.xml file? I'm new to Xcode so just wasn't sure. I have a lot of apps to build, so am looking for a good way to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this, so simply symlinked to the icons in the www directory to their relevant default locations, and this worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

See Resources/Cordova.plist - this is the Xcode equivalent of config.xml